# How to group pandas timestamp column according to whether they are within a threshold time duration or not?

Tags: pandas, loops, optimization, timestamp, cluster-analysis

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['4/20/2022 8:23', '4/20/2022 8:20', '4/20/2022 8:20', '4/20/2022 8:20', '4/20/2022 8:20', '4/20/2022 8:20', '4/20/2022 8:17', '4/20/2022 8:17', '4/20/2022 8:17', '4/20/2022 8:17', '4/20/2022 9:56', '4/20/2022 9:50', '4/20/2022 9:50', '4/20/2022 9:48', '4/20/2022 9:48', '4/20/2022 9:48', '4/20/2022 9:48', '4/20/2022 9:47'],
                  columns=['timestamp'])
```

[image]

I want to add another column called `Cluster` which will put all the rows in the same cluster ID if they occur within, say, a half hour time duration. So, rows 0 to 9 should be cluster 0, and rows 10 to 17 should be cluster 1.

How do I do this in the best way?

I'm doing it in quite a patchy way (but at least correctly, I hope):

```
import numpy as np

df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df['time_diff'] = np.zeros(len(df))

for i in range(len(df)-1):
    df.time_diff[i+1]=np.abs(df.timestamp[i+1]-df.timestamp[i])/ np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
    
cluster = 0
df['cluster'] = np.zeros(len(df))
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.time_diff[i]>0.5:
        cluster+=1
        df.cluster[i:]=cluster
df
```

[image]

I wonder if there's a Pythonic way of doing this, a one-liner perhaps.

Comment: The issue here is that your timestamps are neither unique, nor sorted, this gives ambiguity on how exactly your want to cluster. By time and proximity? Time only?

Answer (score 0):

there is a feature precisely for the temporal sequence conversion.
her name is `resample`.

Below is an example of usage:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start, end = '2000-10-01 23:30:00', '2000-10-02 00:30:00'

rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='7min')
df = pd.Series(np.arange(len(rng)), index=rng)
print("before conversion:")
print(df)
print("after conversion:")
print(df.resample('H').sum())
```

documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Answer (score -1):

You may extract the hour column as  follows:

```
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
    df['hour'] = df['time_stamp'].apply(lambda row: row.hour)
```